# angular2: adding router-outlet causes ngModel not to fire

Tags: angular

I am just experimenting w/ angular 2 beta 9, and I am wondering:

I have a component that binds an input field with:

```
[(ngModel)]="email" (ngModelChange)="changedExtraHandler($event)"
```

The `changedExtraHandler()` fires every time I enter something.

now in the parent component, I add a `router-outlet` plus configuration:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'fv-app',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, HeaderComponent, LoginComponent, RouterOutlet],
    template: `
    <fv-header></fv-header>
    <a [routerLink]="['Login']">Login</a>
    <fv-login></fv-login>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `,
    providers: [
      UserService
    ]
})
@RouteConfig([
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'Login',
    component: LoginComponent
  }
])
export class AppComponent { }
```

It seems to work, the component is displayed two times when I'm on `/login`. However, when I enter something in the component nested under `router-outlet` the `changedExtraHandler()` does not fire. Does anyone know what I am missing?

**Edit**:

So, after some debugging, it turns out that the directive rendered normally without `router-outlet` is set up correctly, and [NgModel#ngOnChanges](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/common/forms/directives/ng_model.ts#L74) calls `setUpControl` which [registers the onChange method](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/common/forms/directives/shared.ts#L27). When the router creates the element this method is not called, thus no updating of the ngModel. Maybe it is because the setup is done in `AbstractChangeDetector#_detectChangesInViewChildren`, which when called for the router-outlet does not detect changes because the Component is not inserted under `<router-outlet>`, but besides it. Just guessing, though, going to investigate further. Any help still greatly appreciated ;)

see here: https://github.com/rweng/ng2-routing

Comment: How do you navigate to that route? A plunker to reproduce would be helpful as well.

Comment: Tried having it as `useAsDefault`, adding `#/login` to the url and linking to it with `[routerLink]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. Problem was, that I assumed the following was enough when bootstrapping the application:

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser'
```

However, it seems zonejs is not loaded correctly, or it is loaded too late. Importing the polyfills right at the start fixes the problem with router as well as other problems with UI not updating correctly:

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills'
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser'
```